# Using output of another class as a variable in other class

Tags: java

I have a program where i'm required to seperate as much out as possible as different methods and classes.

I have a rng, thats a class. I want to use the output from the rng in another class to compare it against a user selection to decide if they win or lose.

This is my rng.

```
package stockGame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; // Import this just in case I need a popup window
import java.util.Random; // Import this so i can use the random number

//The purpose of this class is to generate a random number between 1 and 12
public class Dice {
    public static void Dice(){
        Random random = new Random ();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The Computer picked " + (random.nextInt(12)+1));
    }
}
```

Here is my if loop in the second class. I want to be able to say. If (option ==1 AND RNG is GREATER/LESS/EQUAL to 6){
That way it can compare and decide if the user has won or lost.

```
if (option ==1){
    output = "You chose to trade less than £6 and the computer rolled RNG, so you win/lose,";
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output, "The Message", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);            
}
if (option ==2){
    output = "You chose to trade more than £6";
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output, "The Message", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);        
}
if (option==3){
    output = "You chose to trade exactly £6";
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output, "The Message", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
```

Hoping to get the ouput generated from RNG class to be used in another class

Comment: Before your if checks, get the random val and start comparing... `Dice.getRandomVal()` where `getRandomVal` would return the `random.nextInt(12)+1`

Answer (score 1):

You have to return the value from the Dice Method:

```
public class Dice {
public static int Dice(){
    Random random = new Random ();
    int randomNum = random.nextInt(12)+1;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The Computer picked " + randomNum);
    return randomNum;
  }
}
```

The if-statement should be something like this:

```
if(option == 1 && Dice.Dice() == 6)
{
  //do something
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much both! I knew I needed the return the value but it just didn't make the connection!. I feel so silly.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in order to return something from a method, that method signature must be set to return something different from void, in your case `int`:

```
public class Dice {
    public static int dice() {
        Random random = new Random ();

        int picked = random.nextInt(12)+1;

        return picked;
    }
}
```

and then use it:

```
int picked = Dice.dice();

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The Computer picked " + picked);

if (option == 1 && picked < 6) {
    output = "You chose to trade less than £6 and the computer rolled RNG, so you win/lose,";         
}
if (option == 2 && picked > 6) {
    output = "You chose to trade more than £6";       
}
if (option == 3 && picked == 6) {
    output = "You chose to trade exactly £6";
}

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output, "The Message", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

As you can see, I moved the message outside of the dice method because it's better to let do only a single task for each method, and by doing so you'll can reuse the dice method for other purposes without the need to show the message.